# C# cmd output in real time

Tags: c#, cmd, real-time

I am writing a program that uses a hidden console CMD. Starts in the codec "ffmpeg". When converting all the time gets feedback.

I wish every 1 second charge results from the console. Unfortunately, all the codes available on the internet work on the principle that gets refund after the conversion and I want to be watching you all the time what was happening.

```
public void ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
{
     try
     {
         // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
         // and "/c " as the parameters.
         // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows,
         // and then exit.
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
        new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

    // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
    // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
    procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    // Do not create the black window.
    procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
    proc.Start();
    // Get the output into a string
    string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    // Display the command output.
    Console.WriteLine(result);
      }
      catch (Exception objException)
      {
      // Log the exception
      }
}
```

Comment: Was this produced by Google translate? The "refund" part is highly suspicious.

Comment: fine tip up here :))

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the output without waiting use the async features.
Checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx

Set up eventhandler

```
proc.OutputDataReceived += (s,e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Data);};
```

start async read of standard output

```
proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

I have modified your code to use these features.

```
    public static void ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
    {
        try
        {
            // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
            // and "/c " as the parameters.
            // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows,
            // and then exit.
            var procStartInfo =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);


            // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
            // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // Do not create the black window.
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
            var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.OutputDataReceived += (s,e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Data);};
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + objException.Message);
            // Log the exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but this did not solve my problem. I still do not live what happens in the CMD.

Comment: Added WaitForExit to the code in case thats the problem. 
Could you please explain your situation further?

Answer (score 0):

I sugguest having a look on the Backgroundworker class [MSDN on Backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Here you have a simple callback mechanism to present progress, you just have to provide
a handler that does the progress updates.

From MSDN:

```
// This event handler updates the progress bar.
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,
    ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

With the

```
public void ReportProgress(
int percentProgress,
Object userState)
```

function you can give back any state changes that you want to, especially
the dynamic progress you might need (what is going on in your worker).

But I have to admit that I'm not sure about your "real time" part.