# Status Codes of web pages

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the result out of a web page and to avoid web exceptions I want to check the status code before I request for the result from the stream. However:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
```

throws an exception when I try to get the error code after this using 
`response.StatusCode`

Is there a way to avoid exceptions to get the `StatusCode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask for the StatusCode only after you made a call to the GetResponse() method. You need to wrap GetResponse() in a try/catch block. Have a look at [Check if a url is reachable - Help in optimizing a Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5378429/check-if-a-url-is-reachable-help-in-optimizing-a-class).

If you just want to test for server reachability then you may use a Ping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the   Ping to get more stats from the site. (It's a bit slower tho, takes like 1-3 sec or so)

```
public string ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
    {
        try
        {
            // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
            // and "/c " as the parameters.
            // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows,
            // and then exit.
            var procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);


            // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
            // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // Do not create the black window.
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
            var proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();

            return proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + objException.Message);
            return "";
            // Log the exception
        }
    }
```

[From: [C# cmd output in real time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273409/c-sharp-cmd-output-in-real-time)  Just changed a little]

Usage like:

```
MessageBox.Show(ExecuteCommandSync("ping www.stackoverflow.com"));
```